# Store structure for listed items in Angular

Tags: angular, state, store, rx-angular

I'm using *Angular*, and trying a variety of stores. *RxAngular*, *Elf*, and looking for others. Not looking at *NgRx* because it's too imperative, and doesn't quite make use of observables as you would want in *Angular*

Imagine you have a list of items for sale on a page. The user is an admin who can open any item (say, in a modal window), and change the details. Now, we can have dozens of items, and each item may have many extendes description fields — price, text fields *etc*. The point is, we don't want the Item List page to load all the details of all the items. The `ItemListComponent` should only have the names and ids of the items. When the admin clicks an item, a separate `ItemDetailsComponent` fires up in a modal window, and loads up the necessary details

The question is how to organise the stores for these components (call them `ItemListComponent` and `ItemDetailsComponent`)? Obviously the stores must be different, since, again we don't want the parent store to contain all the details. On the other hand, when the admin clicks an item and changes its name — that change should go live immediately. Not only should it be saved into the database, but it should also be reflected in the parent list. Because — well because this is 2022 people

So the child component should communicate the necessary changes to the parent component, or operate directly (or through a fácáde) on the parent store — in other words, be able to call certain parent's actions. The question is what is the best way to do it, in 2022? In my opinion, those `EventEmitters` are something from 2012. We could alternatively go a bit Reacty, and pass those actions as props into the child component

This problem would have been solved automatically, had we been using say, *Firebase*. Then all the changes to the database would be immediately communicated to whatever components are subscribed to them. But unfortunately, we're not. There isn't a store library, unfortunately, which would act as a "world–wide observable" — where you could `next()` your changes — and it would (1) apply them to the database, and (2) push them to all subscribers (on all devices) ­— which would be an analogue of *Firebase*, but with a complete freedom of the actual database for storage

Suggestions on how you would go about this task?

Comment: `NgRx` does in fact use Observables, when you subscribe to a selector, changes to the store will automatically be propagated to the components via the subscription. In any case I think two separate stores is too complicated when you could just write two different selectors. One which selects the full model for the detail view, and one which only selects the "summary" data. Keeping state consistent in two stores completely defeats the purpose of using a store in the first place as its a mechanism for centralizing and streamlining state management.

Comment: Like I said — there is the data volume problem. There may be dozens if not hundreds of items in the list, each of which contains a significant size of data. I don't want the `ItemListComponent` to load all of that — only the list of `{ id, name }`, roughly speaking. But again, the name (and actually other data) is changed from inside the `ItemDetailsComponent`. Again _Firebase_ would work as a kind of "central" store, had we been using it. Probably _GraphQL_ would solve this too, had we not been using _MySQL_.
In brief — no, I don't think having a single store is the best solution…

Comment: It seems like you have a back-end problem and not a store problem. Nothing is stopping you from writing a selector for the minimal view once the data has been cached in the front-end so the `ItemListComponent` only shows the meager version of the data. So, why not simply write a new endpoint that selects the meager model for your list view and another endpoint for retrieving the detail for specific items?

Comment: This is exactly how it is done on Back End. Roughly speaking "GET /items" returns the list of `{ id, name }` and "GET /items/:id" returns the extensive details for a specific item. The problem is on the Front End — the child component needs to update the parent component. And no, I don't want to refresh the entire list only because the child component changes `name`.

The inventory will not change much, but it will grow over the years. That means, that the item list will be containing potentially hundreds of items — don't want to fetch all their details. Hence, two different stores